# Do I need to use a transaction when renaming a column using C# SMO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I am using c# and the MS SMO library to make a table designer/editor much like that in SQL Server Management Studio. To edit a column, it seems natural to try to set the "Name" property and call the Alter method on the column, but that throws an exception. There is a Rename() method on the column object but that renames the column immediately when called and does not update external references (breaks everything) and I want to force the user to hit a "Save" button to commit the changes. I know how to write a script to rename a column using sp_Rename but I am trying to use the SMO library and use T-SQL scripting only when necessary. Is using a transaction on the connection object with a rollback if the user does not click the save button the only reasonable way to do column renaming using C# SMO?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. sp_rename does NOT go through all your procedures, views etc and change the columns anywhere it finds them. In fact when you call sp_rename it prints a message for you. "Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures."

Comment: oops! Glad you pointed that out to me. I am still looking to use the SMO library anyway. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: So just rename it using Rename().

Comment: If I use Rename() the change is immediate. I don't want that. Otherwise I have to call Rename again if the user decides to cancel his changes in my form.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to cache the user's request for name changes and then submit all the changes in one go in a transaction. I thought I might be misusing the SMO library, overlooking a simpler solution.

Comment: Wouldn't call the Rename method after the user hits save as part of the save logic? If the user hits cancel you simply don't do anything.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.